# applescript get rid of full path

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

I've got a `choose file` in my AppleScript. When I run the script and choose a file, the output is always the full file path with the file extension on the end. For example:

```
Macintosh HD:Developer:About Xcode.pdf
```

is what I don't want. I only want:

```
About Xcode
```

---

---

The below answer by `Kassym Dorsel` doesn't work when there is more than one `.` in it.

The below answer by Lri doesn't work with `set x to choose file`:

```
error "Can’t make quoted form of alias \"Macintosh HD:Applications:Firefox.app:\" into        type Unicode text." number -1700 from quoted form of alias "Macintosh HD:Applications:Firefox.app:" to Unicode text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Finder to manipulate the names of Finder items:

```
choose file with prompt "Pick one"
set filepath to result

tell application "Finder" to set {dispName, nameExt, isHidden} to ¬
    the {displayed name, name extension, extension hidden} of the filepath


if isHidden or nameExt is equal to "" then
    dispName
else
    (characters 1 through (-2 - (count of nameExt)) of dispName) as text
end if

set baseName to result
```

Comment: @Lri Thanks for catching that about the extension; fixed. Since the file is selected using `choose file`, the file will always exist -- you need to use `choose file name` to get a reference to a file that may not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
set a to "Macintosh HD:Developer:About.Xcode.pdf"
set text item delimiters to ":"
set temp to last text item of a
set text item delimiters to "."
set temp to text items 1 thru -2 of temp as text
```

Gives => `About.Xcode`

Comment: This fails when the file name has more than one `.` character.

Comment: My initial solution was case specific, yes. I have updated my solution to allow for periods in the filename. It should now work for everything.